# Getting updated redux state after dispatch with react hooks

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using the action expensesActions.getExpenseList to get a list from the database, which in turns updates the store in expense.expenseList
I'm calling the action inside useEffect hook and would like to get back the list from the store once it's retreived.

My code below is not working because the order is incorrect, if I refresh (with save) I do have the list. How can I change the code so my list is retreived once the actions is complete?

```
   const fetchedList = useSelector(state => state.expense.expenseList);

    // Get expense list
    useEffect(() => {
      const loadList = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        await dispatch(expensesActions.getExpenseList())
        calculateAverageExpense()
      }
      loadList()
      }, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: You can have a second useEffect like this:
useEffect(() =>{ if (fetchedList.length) calculateAverageExpense(); }, [fetchedList])
This will execute calculateAverageExpense every time your list change.

Comment: Oh you're right now it seems so simple thanks a lot, please change it to an answer and I will accept

Comment: No problem, hooks change a bit how to think components. Sometimes it can be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a second useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (fetchedList.length) calculateAverageExpense();
}, [fetchedList])
```

This will execute calculateAverageExpense every time your list change.